# How to get objects between two timestamps by an user

Tags: javascript, loops, object, timestamp

I would like to loop through all my objects for users which have created two or more objects (`createdAt`) in one day. (00:00:00 - 23:59:59) epoch for one day: 86400 seconds). I want to do this for all the days within, let's say a year. Is this possible and how to achieve this?

Results can be an array of the users which have created two or more objects on the same day.

I got a Firebase database set up which contains the following structure:

`{
"-KFNn8CA5QdxuhJaaatw" : {
    "some" : "data",
    "createdAt" : 1460704940,
    "points" : 0,
    "userKey" : 1
  },
-KFNn8CA5QdxuhJW11tw" : {
    "some" : "data",
    "createdAt" : 1460704940,
    "points" : 0,
    "userKey" : 1
  },
-KFNn8CA5QdxuhJW66tw" : {
    "some" : "data",
    "createdAt" : 1460704940,
    "points" : 0,
    "userKey" : 3
  },
  -KFNn8CA5QdxuhJW6123w" : {
    "some" : "data",
    "createdAt" : 1460704940,
    "points" : 0,
    "userKey" : 5
  }
.....
}`

Comment: do you need to see if they created two objects in an interval of 86400 seconds or per day (00:00-23:59:59) ?

Comment: per day 00:00-23:59:59

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I got:

```
var arr = {
    "-KFNn8CA5QdxuhJaaatw" : {
        "some" : "data",
        "createdAt" : 1460704940,
        "points" : 0,
        "userKey" : 1
    },
    "-KFNn8CA5QdxuhJW11tw" : {
        "some" : "data",
        "createdAt" : 1460704940,
        "points" : 0,
        "userKey" : 1
    },
    "-KFNn8CA5QdxuhJW66tw" : {
        "some" : "data",
        "createdAt" : 1460704940,
        "points" : 0,
        "userKey" : 3
    },
    "-KFNn8CA5QdxuhJW6123w" : {
        "some" : "data",
        "createdAt" : 1460704940,
        "points" : 0,
        "userKey" : 5
    }
};
// keeps a reference of the last object a user created
var dict = {};
// using an object, so we get distinct values
var userKeys = {};
// getting a list of objects ordered by creation time
var objs = Object.keys(arr).map(function (k) {
        return arr[k];
    });
objs.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.createdAt - b.createdAt;
});
objs.forEach(function (obj) {
    // if dict holds an object for this user, compare if they were created in the same day
    if (dict[obj.userKey]) {
        if (inSameDay(dict[obj.userKey].createdAt, obj.createdAt)) {
            userKeys[obj.userKey] = true;
        }
    }
    // store the object the user created last
    dict[obj.userKey] = obj;
});
// get ids as an array
var users = Object.keys(userKeys);

// compare if two datetimes are in the same day
function inSameDay(t1, t2) {
    var d1 = new Date(t1 * 1000);
    var d2 = new Date(t2 * 1000);
    return d1.getFullYear() == d2.getFullYear() &&
    d1.getMonth() == d2.getMonth() &&
    d1.getDate() == d2.getDate();
}
```

In the end, the `users` array will contain the keys of the users that have created two objects in the same day.

If you want to have more information than what you asked, create a data structure that groups by the data you want to query on, then it is easy to get any result you want. Here is an example:

```
// this is an object containing all the data
// grouped by userKey and date
var data = {}
Object.keys(arr).forEach(function (key) {
    var obj = arr[key];
    var userData = data[obj.userKey];
    if (!userData) {
        data[obj.userKey] = (userData = {});
    }
    var date = new Date(obj.createdAt * 1000);
    var dateString = date.getFullYear() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate();
    var dateData = userData[dateString];
    if (!dateData) {
        userData[dateString] = (dateData = []);
    }
    dateData.push(obj);
});
// this is an array of userKeys for users with
// two or more items created per day
var users = Object.keys(data)
    .filter(function (userKey) {
        var dates = Object.keys(data[userKey]);
        for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
            if (data[userKey][dates[i]].length >= 2)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
// and this is their data
var dataOfUsers = {};
users.forEach(function (userKey) {
    dataOfUsers[userKey] = data[userKey];
});
```

Comment: wow! Thanks for your reply! Somehow there is something wrong in  for checking the same day, it's comparing two different users with each other?

Comment: Thanks great Siderite!! Somehow all the users are `true`, must be something wrong with checking if the same day?

Comment: What is the best way to extend this code by counting how much this occurs for a specific user? e.g. user `y` has created `x` objects within that day

Comment: I've updated the answer for more complex queries. Also, if you need to do complex queries in Javascript, take at look at : http://linqjs.codeplex.com/ It will simplify much.